# Unable to resize image by percentage for slider banner

Tags: html, css

I am going through this guide for a slider banner:
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kFoGw

When I tried to resize the image to makes it smaller and centered, I only managed to adjust the width.

```
figure.slider img { width: 50%; height: 50%; margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
```

I read other answers saying I need to fit a Height:100% and Width:100% as parents but I can't find out where do I add it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve? Could you post a simple diagram?

Generally with a carousel the images will stretch 100% width of the container (parent) div.

As a general rule I would not apply a height style as it will likely deform. Images should be scaled by width and this will keep the correct aspect ratio for the image.

Maybe try to apply your custom settings to the container:

```
div#captioned-gallery {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Instead of of the whole image filling the browser from side to side, I am trying to make it smaller and centered. I can adjust the width but I can't adjust the height by %, only by px. I also can't make it centered.

This is what I tried to adjust---
figure.slider img { width: 50%; height: 200px; }